# Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra, Third Edition

Tags: abstract-algebra, book-recommendation

It has been not a long time since the monolithic Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra has been re-published, in a reorganized, two volumes new edition. Do you know if and how the two volumes of this third edition differ in quality and quantity from the previous one? I read the respective tables of contents and I have only a vague idea about this. I think it would be useful if someone has a more concrete, fact-based opinion about possible differences between them, with also an (always personal, I know) judgement about which text would be preferable in which context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may find the MAA reviews interesting, since they compare the latest 3rd edition to the previous ones:

https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/advanced-modern-algebrathird-edition-part-1

https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/advanced-modern-algebra-third-edition-part-2

Comment: I'll also be reviewing the book at my website for the AMS before January. The book basically differs from the second edition mainly in it's organization and some clarification, there are mostly the same topics. Rotman was one of  the great mathematics textbook writers of his generation and it was very sad to hear he'd passed. He's left behind an amazing legacy of books for future generations.

Comment: Yeah, @Mathemagician1234, it was very sad news, really.
So it seems that the two books have more or less the same contents, albeit arranged in a different way. Anyway, as the reviewer says, it is probably wroth possessing both editions to take advantage of their different natures, i.e. the compendious and the pedagogical one, respectively.